# Permissions working but not working

Tags: permissions, server, apache

Not sure what I changed in my Wordpress some days ago but today I was not able to update/install any plugin. I followed https://community.bitnami.com/t/wordpress-permissions-unable-to-create-directory/42048/3 and applied the following permissions:

```
sudo find ~/apps/wordpress/htdocs/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
sudo find ~/apps/wordpress/htdocs/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

sudo chmod 750 ~/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-config.php
sudo find ~/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
sudo find ~/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
sudo chmod 750 ~/apps/wordpress/htdocs

sudo chown -R bitnami:daemon ~/apps/wordpress/htdocs
sudo chown -R bitnami:daemon ~/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins
sudo chown -R bitnami:bitnami ~/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/upgrade
sudo chown -R daemon:daemon ~/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/uploads
```

Now I CAN update and install plugins but:
- It takes longer, roughly twice as much time than some days ago (before it broke).
- It tells me the install/update was unsuccesful even though it did it!

> The update cannot be installed because we were unable to copy some files. This is usually due to inconsistent file permissions.

Of course, it is not that bad, but I would like to have it as it should be, not with such a result.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now. For those wondering, there was something wrong with the symlinks so I just went back to the original WP permissions.

```
sudo chown -R bitnami:daemon /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/
sudo find /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/ -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
sudo find /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/ -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
sudo chmod 640 /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-config.php
```

I semi-modified the answer from here: https://community.bitnami.com/t/cant-update-wordpress-plugin/72068/6

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the user running on behalf of the webserver's PHP process has ownership permissions on `/path/to/wordpress`

### Example

For Ubuntu 18.04 running Apache2

```
# Go to wordpress installation root directory
cd /path/to/wordpress

# Give ownership to Apache2's PHP process
sudo chown www-data:www-data .

# Apply files and directories permissions
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} +
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} +
sudo chmod 644 wp-config.php
```

Comment: Hi @Felipe Romero, not sure if we are on the same page. there is no path/to/wordpress in my installation of Bitnami Wordpress or at least I can't find it. If you need some info to know exactly what I am running please tell me how to get it and I will find out.

Comment: Hi @AdrianInfante don't take it literal, `/path/to/wordpress` is a _placeholder_ for where your current wordpress installation is. The installation directory tends to be different from server to server so this is a way to represent a variable path. In your specific case your `/path/to/wordpress` is `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress`.